# Is -2n a big Oh of n as n goes to infinity?

Tags: asymptotics

Based on the definition of the upper asymptotic bound, we have that :

$$|n| < K |-2n| $$

for $ K = 1$ for example and as $ n $ goes to $+\infty$, so the definition would lead us to say that $-2n$ is an asymptotic **upper** bound of $n$; Which doesn't make sense since $-2n$ is obviously smaller than $n$.

Comment: I would say $-2n$ is less than $n$, but not "smaller than" $n$.  Anyway, big O only looks at the absolute values.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What counts is the $\color{red}{magnitude}$ of a general term,  as $n\to \infty$,
$$
O(-2n)=O(|-2n|)=O(2n)=O(n),
$$ we are considering absolute values here.

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$$ \frac{f(n)}{n}\to k\in \mathbb{R}\implies f(n)=O(n)$$

thus $$O(n)=O(-2n) \quad n\to+\infty$$

Comment: Your first line is false. Only the $\Leftarrow$ direction is true. See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2589685/5531).

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is not the sign but the "size". That's why the definition uses the absolute value. In that sense $-2n$ is *larger* than $n$.